# Flask-mail ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054]

Tags: python, flask, flask-mail

I am trying to send an email using `Flask-mail` but for some reason it always give me this error

```
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054]
```

By the way, I already configured my Gmail account to allow low security applications.

Here is the code:

```py
from flask import Flask  
from flask_mail import Mail, Message

app =Flask(__name__)

app.config['MAIL_SERVER']='smtp.gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 587
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = 'sender.gmail'
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = 'sender.password'
app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS'] = False
app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL'] = True

mail = Mail(app)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    msg = Message('Hello', sender = 'sender.gmail', recipients = ['reciever.gmail'])
    msg.body = "Hello there!"
    mail.send(msg)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration seems confusing. When you set the username and the password as something like 'sender.gmail' and 'sender.password' which is string (It's not going to be changed anywhere else in your code), certainly, that user wont be recognized by smtp.gmail.com .

Use something real, like `kyllex@gmail.com` and `sup3rp4ssw0rd`.

flask_mail [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Mail/).

Comment: I do set them for a real gmail  and password just for security purpose I change them to sender and reciever. Thank you

Comment: have you use and open the correct port? since SMTPS use port 465